# Degeneracy number of a ring graph

Tags: graph-theory

The definition of $k-$ [degeneracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_%28graph_theory%29) is not clear to me. Could someone please explain how is degeneracy number different from maximum degree $\Delta G$ of the graph $G$? And second question is, does a ring graph has $k=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tree has leaves, and therefore is $1$-degenerate, while the max degree is unlimited.

If by the ring graph you mean a cycle, then every subgraph of the cycle only has vertices of the degree $1$ and $2$, thus the cycle is $2$-degenerate.

Comment: So is it $\max \{ \mathrm{mindeg}(s): s\in S \}$, where $S$ is the set of all subsets of graph $G$?, So if we take a star graph with center node having $K$ edges so that there are $K+1$ nodes, is the degenercy $1$ ?thanks.

Comment: @triomphe Yes, exactly.

Comment: You said a ring is $2$- degenerate. I see that every subgraph of a ring has a node with degree one. So why $2$? I really need to understand this point. Thaks.

Comment: @triomphe your last formulation is wrong, degeneracy is $$\min\{\max \mathrm{deg}(s) | s \in S\}.$$
This way, tree is 1-degenerate and cycle is 2-degenerate and star is 1-degenerate also. I got confused myself also, sorry.

Comment: By this formulation cycle will be $0$ or $1$ degenerate because I can take a subgraph of a cycle with just two adjecent nodes that has one edge. The maxdegree of this subgraph is $1$. I can even just take a single node with no edges, which is also a subgraph and it has maxdegree $0$?

Comment: @triomphe yes, i am now confused too. the definition on wiki does not restrict graph size. need to look more into it, i am sorry.